# Is is possible to coordinate the animation in 2 plots with gganimate

Tags: r, shiny, gganimate

I would like to have 2 animated plots, with go in sync. So perhaps I have a dataset with 3 columns (time, x and y), and as we step through time, the plot for x and the plot for y move in step.
Moreover, I would like this to be in an R-shiny app, with a button, called 'make a step' which controls the animation. 
I was hoping to use gganimate, and then all I would need is a way to set the frame currently displayed. Is that possible?

Many thanks,

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, referring to multiple concepts (`gganimate`, `shiny`). In order to get the best (most useful) response you should consider rephrasing your question and including sample data. Better still, include a code attempt. There are a few posts around (here on SO and on the wider web) that demonstrate at least the "animation of two linked plots" part, see e.g. [issue #140 from `gganimate`](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/140). The easier you make it for others to answer, the more answers you will get (and the better the answers will be)!

Comment: You are quite right. Let me rephrase the question: With gganimate, how can I start and stop the animation, and -once stopped- how can I set the frame it is currently showing?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work. Monitoring the `Make a step` button with a `reactiveVal` to update a dataset and re-render the plots.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

dd  <- tibble(Time = 1:10,
              x = 1:10,
              y = 1:10*10)

ui <- basicPage(column(1, actionButton("make_a_step", "Make a step")),
                column(4, plotOutput("p1")),
                column(4, plotOutput("p2")))

server <- function(input, output) {
  n_steps <- reactiveVal(value = 0)

  observeEvent(input$make_a_step,{
    new_steps <- n_steps() + 1
    n_steps(new_steps)
  })

  plot_fun <- function(df, x_or_y) {
    ggplot(df, aes(x = "Time", y = !!as.name(x_or_y))) + geom_point()
  }

  sub_fun <- function(steps) {
    validate(need(steps <= 10, "You've reached the last time point"))
    dd[1:steps,]
  }

  output$p1 <- renderPlot({
    plot_fun(sub_fun(n_steps()), "x")
  })

  output$p2 <- renderPlot({
    plot_fun(sub_fun(n_steps()), "y")
  })

}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes, that works. Now I had really just put a minimal example to show what I mean. What I in fact is this app here

Comment: https://oldmortality.shinyapps.io/app6/   When you click the start button, the animation runs over 3 plots simultaneously. The problem is that when I have 30 students in the lab all running this at once, it becomes slow and erratic. I was thinking I might speed this up by generating all data in advance, and then use gganimate to do the animation. But perhaps that won't actually be any faster or essentially different from your code above